# How to invoke `git show` only for the latest fetched branches?

Tags: git, git-fetch, git-show

I've repository with hundreds of branches and I'd like to run `git show` only for these which have been recently fetched or updated as shown by `git fetch`, e.g.

```
$ git fetch tester
From repo:Foo/Bar
 * [new branch]      Foo -> origin/Foo
   a7e70a8..a9d7805  Bar -> origin/Bar
 + b673629...293dc64 Baz -> origin/Baz (forced update)
 + 345850e...b3646a3 Qux -> origin/Qux (forced update)
```

So I'd like to end up with the command like:

```
git show origin/Foo origin/Bar origin/Baz origin/Qux
```

which will show me the differences between these recent fetched branches and their parents commit(s).

How this can be achieved?

---

I've tried `git show FETCH_HEAD`, but it shows me only one branch along with the warning that refname 'FETCH_HEAD' is ambiguous.

And `git show $(git branch -r --sort=authordate | head)` shows me much older branches, secondly the command breaks on lines with `->`, so it doesn't work either.

Comment: Side note: `git show origin/Foo` does not show the difference between `origin/Foo` and `master` (except in one special case). It shows the difference between `origin/Foo` and its parent commit(s). If there is just one parent commit of `origin/Foo`, and that parent commit is also the commit named by `master`, then you get that one special case. (And, `git show <c1> <c2> <c3>` shows each of the named commits in order, by the usual diff-commit-against-its-parent(s).)

Comment: @torek Corrected that it's showing the differences between parent commit(s).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the recently updated branches by using `for-each-ref`

```
git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate refs/remotes/origin
```

Use `--format=%(objectname)` to get the heads of those branches. This get the five most recently updated branches,

```
git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate --format="%(objectname)" refs/remotes/origin | head -5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution involving parsing of the `git` output, e.g.

```
git fetch tester 2>&1 | grep -o "origin/\S\+" | xargs git show
```

<sup>Replace `origin` with name of your remote host.</sup>

You can use `--dry-run` parameter to test it first (before fetching the branches), e.g.

```
git fetch tester --dry-run 2>&1 | grep -o "origin/\S\+"
```